# Error in R: no applicable method for 'xpathApply'

Tags: xml, r, xpath, odata, xml2

I am trying to retrieve data in R from an oData source. This script worked, but after i updated some packages, the script required the xml2 package, which caused an error.

```
library('httr') # for sending http requests
library("xml2") # for reading xml

# log start of request
log_message(paste("Requesting OData from:",url))

# get the OData resource
response <- GET(url,authenticate(usr,pwd))

# parse xml docucument
responseContent <- content(response,type="text/xml")

# determine the names of the attributes
xmlNames <- xpathApply(responseContent,
                        '//ns:entry[1]//m:properties[1]/d:*',xmlName, 
                        namespaces = c(ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
                                       m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata",
                                       d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"))
```

When determining the names of the attributes i get the following error. Does anyone know what this error message means and how I can solve it?

> Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
>     no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow omi. Please take a look at  [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. You may also find this [R example making link helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - I recommend you show `library(packages)` in yoru code above and use `sessionInfo()` to give the names of versions so people can try track down your error.

Comment: Another tip - Please check out `packrat` package which lets you freeze/choose/rollback your package versions so you don't have this drama. Its from Rstudio so if you are using their IDE it will be easy to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`httr` switched to using `xml2` recently in `v1.1.0` i think. If you use `content(x)` on xml data you get an `xml2` object back. You can do that, and do something like (not tested)

```
xml_find_all(x, '//ns:entry[1]//m:properties[1]/d:*', xml_ns(x))
```

or parse to text like `content(x, as = "text")`, which gives you character string, then do `XML::xmlParse()`, then you can proceed as normal with your `XML` based workflow

Comment: Thanks @sckott, I decided to switch back to a previous version of httr to avoid this problem for the time being.

Comment: note that with the new httr you also have to set encoding explicitly, usually `content(..., encoding = "UTF-8")`